# Can I control how many cells stay in memory in a UICollectionView (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Is it possible to keep more cells in memory? I am having trouble with scrolling. Could I, for instance, keep 3 screens worth of cells in memory instead of just one?

If so, how could one do that?

Below is a screenshot of some of my cells. It is just 3 labels. They are self-sizing. Maybe that is what is taking so long.

[image]

Or it might very well be that I am doing something wrong in my `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Here is that code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let wordCell: ReadArticleCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("wordCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ReadArticleCollectionViewCell

        wordCell.pronunciationLabelView.hidden = false
        wordCell.pronunciationLabelView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        wordCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
        wordCell.layer.shadowRadius = 0
        wordCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        wordCell.underlineLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        var arrayOfParagraphsOfWordStrings = [[String]]()

        for paragraph in self.arrayOfParagraphsOfSentencesOfWordStrings { 
            arrayOfParagraphsOfWordStrings.append(paragraph.reduce([], +)) //is this my culprit? I am doing this so I can use a 3d array as a 2d array datasource but still later be able to map from the 2d array's index to the corresponding index in the 3d array.
        }

        if let word = arrayOfParagraphsOfWordStrings[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as String? {

            if let pinyinArrayForWord = self.pinyinArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as String? {

                if let pinyin = convertPinyinNumbersToToneMarks(self.pinyinArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]) as String? {
                    wordCell.pronunciationLabelView.text = pinyin
                }
                else {
                    wordCell.pronunciationLabelView.text = self.pinyinArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
                }

                if wordCell.pronunciationLabelView.text == "" {
                    wordCell.pronunciationLabelView.text = "n/a"
                    wordCell.pronunciationLabelView.hidden = true
                }

                if self.pinyinQuantityArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] > 1 {
//                  println(pinyinQuantityArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
                    wordCell.pronunciationLabelView.textColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
                }
            }

            if word == "Score Paragraph" {
                wordCell.wordLabelView.hidden = false
                wordCell.pronunciationLabelView.hidden = true
                wordCell.pronunciationLabelView.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            }

            switch self.wordScoreArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] {
            case 5...10:
                wordCell.pronunciationLabelView.hidden = true
            case 1...10:
                wordCell.underlineLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            case (-10)...(-1):
                wordCell.underlineLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            default:
                wordCell.underlineLabelView.backgroundColor = wordCell.underlineLabelView.backgroundColor
            }

            if self.wordTouchedArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] == true {
//              wordCell.underlineLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
//              wordCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 20)
                wordCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75
                wordCell.layer.shadowRadius = 6
                wordCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
//              wordCell.underlineLabelView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
//              wordCell.underlineLabelView.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
//              wordCell.underlineLabelView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
//              wordCell.underlineLabelView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
            }

            if self.wordLookedUpArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] == true {
//              wordCell.underlineLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                wordCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75
                wordCell.layer.shadowRadius = 6
                wordCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
            }

            wordCell.wordLabelView.text = arrayOfParagraphsOfWordStrings[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        }

        return wordCell
    }
```

Comment: You should revise your code to avoid all long-running process in UI thread. Even if you can increase number of screens in memory, you still have problem with loading the 4th screen that will be displayed in the screen when you scroll.

Comment: I do want to avoid long-running process in the UI thread, however I am a programming newbie and am just trying to get this off the ground. Right now I can only scroll less than an inch before major lagging starts. At least if I kept more cells in memory I could scroll further and then read a bit and then more cells would be loading in the background (right?) and then I could scroll again and read a little bit more.

Comment: "is this my culprit?" Yes, that's the one!

Answer (score 0):

> Could I, for instance, keep 3 screens worth of cells in memory instead of just one?

There is no point to keep more than a single screen worth of cells in memory, because they are rendered one screen at a time. Cells represent a view in MVC structure, so you need to create only as many as you need.

On the other hand, keeping the *data* for your cells in memory makes perfect sense. Data represents a model in MVC; that is where the caching should happen.

> Right now I can only scroll less than an inch before major lagging starts.

This happens because of the code in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` needs to access data that has not been cached in your data source. To fix this problem split the code that prepares your cells into two parts: one part that fetches and caches the data and prepares everything that you need to make a `UICollectionViewCell` without actually making it, and another part that takes a possibly recycled `UICollectionViewCell`, quickly pairs it up with the data from the cache, and sends it on its way to `UICollectionView`.

**EDIT :** (in response to the edit of the question)

```
var arrayOfParagraphsOfWordStrings = [[String]]()
for paragraph in self.arrayOfParagraphsOfSentencesOfWordStrings { 
    arrayOfParagraphsOfWordStrings.append(paragraph.reduce([], +))
}
```

> is this my culprit? I am doing this so I can use a 3d array as a 2d array datasource but still later be able to map from the 2d array's index to the corresponding index in the 3d array.

Yes, that is the problem. You perform this conversion for every single cell, and then you take a single word from it. You should refactor your code to move this specific part into some other place, store `arrayOfParagraphsOfWordStrings` in an instance variable, and use it in your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` code without rebuilding it for each cell.

Comment: Maybe I asked the wrong question. How about this: Can I preload offscreen cells so I can at least scroll a little bit before the lag?

Comment: @webmagnets You do not need to pre-make whole offscreen cells, only the most expensive parts of them (usually, that's images). Make a collection of these, perhaps looking ahead a few screens, and store them in memory. This way your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method would spend zero time looking up the expensive parts, turning the cells around very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You should move this code to a ViewDidload or ViewWillAppear (before loading Collection view). You re-call this each time you get your cell to be drawn. It's unnecessary, I suppose.

```
var arrayOfParagraphsOfWordStrings = [[String]]()

for paragraph in self.arrayOfParagraphsOfSentencesOfWordStrings { 
    arrayOfParagraphsOfWordStrings.append(paragraph.reduce([], +)) //is this my culprit? I am doing this so I can use a 3d array as a 2d array datasource but still later be able to map from the 2d array's index to the corresponding index in the 3d array.
}
```